# How to send an automatic message in android without using any buttons

Tags: android-intent

Could u please help me to send a sms automatically from an android app when we open or invoke the application itself....I prefer not to use buttons for click to send the same sms to another phone

Answer (score 0):

Your problem consists of two parts:

1. Invoke code when app launches
2. Sending SMS.

First, to invoke a code when app launches, use onCreate(), onResume() or onStart(), on example:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
  super.onStart();

  // code here
}
```

Which one to use is up to you and your requirements. Please read [this explanation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for more info.

Second is sending SMS. This one is pretty straightforward:

```
SmsManager smsMgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsMgr.sendTextMessage(phone_number, null, text, null, null);
```

Please find SmsManager.sendTextMessage() docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.app.PendingIntent, android.app.PendingIntent)).

So, your complete code could look like this:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
  super.onStart();

  String phone_number = "44123456789"; // some phone number here
  String text = "SMS text here";

  SmsManager smsMgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
  smsMgr.sendTextMessage(phone_number, null, text, null, null);
}
```

**Note:** yo send SMS messages, your app need [SEND_SMS permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SEND_SMS). To declare it, add the following line to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
```